# Compile angular 2 html from string

Tags: angular

Lets say I have this string in database.

```
databaseEntry = "<span (click)="togleShowDetails()">click here</span>"
```

I want it to work the same as if I put the same string directly into my code.
I tried this:

```
<p [innerHTML]="databaseEntry"></p>
<span (click)="someFunction()">click here</span>
```

Both lines render visually the same but click function works only on second because in fact the generated HTML is different.

```
<span>click here</span>
<span _ngcontent-qdv-71="" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">click here</span>
```

It is because the first one isn't regenerated by angular.

So the question is what to use instead of innerHTML.
I found some answers for this but none was considering random input string or lacked something crucial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Milad that a directive can be a good approach but I didn't found solution that way maybe someone smarter is needed.

But we found a workaround:

```
innerText = <string>this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.parseMessage(databaseEntry));
```

But than you need to add custom listener:

```
setTimeout(() => {
     try {
        document.getElementById(IDinDatabaseentryhtmlstring).addEventListener("click", () => this.myClick(LINKinDatabaseEntryHtmlString));
     }
     catch (e) {
        console.log("cannot find element");
        return;
      }
}, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a directive that accepts some text as an input and then compiles and creates a components and then puts it in the element.

Have a look at ngIf and this is somewhat simillar.